# Adding additional databases in Postgresql using CircleCI

Tags: postgresql, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I'm having issues with my CircleCI build and I was hoping someone could help me out.

I am using the `circleci/postgres` image and giving it `POSTGRES_USER`, `POSTGRES_DB` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` environment values.

```
- image: circleci/postgres:11.7
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_DB: main
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
```

Later down my config file after I run some tests, I want to create some additional databases, I'm doing this like so;

```
- run:
    name: "Creating Account Databases"
    command: |
      apk add postgresql-client
      createdb -h localhost temporary -O postgres
      createdb -h localhost temporaryother -O postgres
```

The problem is that when circle ci runs it, i get the following error;

```
createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

I'm unsure of how to fix this, Im not defining a root role anywhere so i am unsure of whats going on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By default when you are trying to create, the current user will be take as database user. You may need to specify -U postgres to create but which may require password. The other way is switch to user postgres using command - sudo su postgres and execute createdb.